# Integral $\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-(\ln x)^2}}dx$

Tags: integration

It surely should be solved using integration by parts, but I don't know how to proceed:
$$
\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-(\ln x)^2}}dx
$$
I tried having $du=1/x$ and thus $u=\ln x$, but then I don't know how to deal with the $(\ln x)^2$ in the denominator. Can anybody help please?

Comment: Substitution, not parts.Let $u=\ln x$.  Then we are finding $\int \frac{1}{(1-u^2)^{1/2}}\,du$, probably familiar.

Answer (score 4):

Following the suggestion in Andre Nicolas's comment, you can let $u=\ln x, du=\frac{1}{x}dx$ to get

$\;\;\;\;\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\;du = \sin^{-1}u+C=\sin^{-1}(\ln x)+C$.

Comment: (+1) This is the correct version of what Nilan was attempting.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $$\ln x=\sin y.$$ $$\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-(\ln x)^2}}dx=\int dy=y+c$$ Therfore$$\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-(\ln x)^2}}dx=\arcsin(\ln x)+c,$$ where $c$ is an arbitary constant.

Comment: (I'm not sure how you got $\int\sec y dy$.)

Comment: @user84413: It seems like $$\begin{align}\int\frac1{x\sqrt{1-\log(x)^2}}\mathrm{d}x &=\int\frac1{\sqrt{1-\log(x)^2}}\mathrm{d}\log(x)\\ &=\int\frac1{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(y)}}\mathrm{d\sin(y)}\\ &=\int\mathrm{d}y\end{align}$$

Comment: @robjohn: Ohh. Thank you. I will edit it.